Отключение приглашений на сервер discord.py
Какова задача: мне нужно чтобы бот по команде просто деактивировал все приглашения созданные для этого сервера. Хочу воссоздать этакую "изоляцию сервера", но мне нужен именно метод деактивации приглашений. Гуглить уже пытался.
Я представляю это примерно так:
@bot.command()
async def save_us(ctx):
    for i in ctx.guild.invitations: # просто цикл for с списком всех приглашений
        i.disable() # удаление приглашения или типа того


Я немного не понимаю целей деактивации, почему не удалять приглашения? Комментарии в коде вроде предполагают удаление...

всё верно. Удалить, деактивировать - разница не принципиальна

Разница принципиальная! Деактивация сохраняет канал, и в последствии Вы можете активировать его повторно (при необходимости). Ссылки на Ваш сервер не имеют ценности!?

мне нужно чтобы приглашения просто деактивировались. Про каналы вообще никто ничего не говорил

Вот методы API, которые Вам надо изучить:

discord.abc.GuildChannel.create_invite
дополню
позже
убежала
discord.on_invite_create
discord.Guild.invites_paused
discord.Guild.invites_paused_until
discord.on_invite_delete

Используйте соответствующие методы фреймворка для решения Вашей задачи.
